# matlab: average group size of the same numbers

Tags: string, matlab, search, grouping

I have a string like

```
a = 011112220010111122221110101111222201111111100022221111101101011...
```

and I want to find an average size of a group of 0s, 1s and 2s (in this example will be  roughly around 3-4 for all of them). Any simple way of doing that?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function:

```
function avg = avg_group_size(s, g)
assert(all(ischar(s)) && ischar(g) && numel(g) == 1, 'bad input');
s = s(:); % column
not_g = char(g + 1);
s_prev = [not_g; s(1 : end - 1)];
s_next = [s(2 : end); not_g];
idx_first   = find(s_prev ~= g & s == g);
idx_last    = find(s_next ~= g & s == g);
avg = mean(idx_last - idx_first + 1);
return
```

and call it:

```
avg_0 = avg_group_size(a, '0');
```

...

But it's not very efficient way. If speed is important, you need to calculate all averages in one loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know matlab but I can write a pseudo code and you can use it.

```
int zeros <- 0 
int ones <- 0 
...
for(i = 0 ; i < a.lenght(or size) ; i++)
   if(a[i] == 0)
     zeros++
   else if(a[i] == 1)
     ones++
...
(or you can use switch case statement)
```